# ruby-odbc and ruby 3.2.2: undefined symbol: rb_tainted_str_new

Tags: ruby, odbc

ruby-odbc is on error on ruby 3.2.x because of :

```
ruby-odbc-0.99999/lib/odbc.so: undefined symbol: rb_tainted_str_new
```

Indead, the ruby C methods `rb_tainted_str_new` is now removed. Do you know if there is any patch to solve that?

And generally, is there anyone maintaining this gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the gem isn't driving any logic with the taint mechanism, it can be trivially patched by replacing `rb_tainted_str_new` with `rb_str_new` (which should include replacing `rb_tainted_str_new2` with `rb_str_new2`) and removing any calls to `rb_obj_taint`.

It looks like someone already forked ruby-odbc to do this: https://github.com/vhermecz/ruby-odbc/commit/c38d182863b907f9ce55d2dfeb9bd86e698f8968

In your gemfile, you can install their patched version:

```
gem 'ruby-odbc', github: 'vhermecz/ruby-odbc'
```

Comment: Thanks, the fix ywork just fine. I am glad the patch had already be done, and that I do not have to do it myself. Hope this gem will have an official fix.